# when using the llvm pass on a program, error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: compiler-errors, clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-clang

A simple LLVM pass example, for LLVM-7.0.0. 
I get this error when trying to run:

> clang -I~/clang_llvm2/include -Xclang -load -Xclang build/skeleton/libSkeletonPass.* test/a.cpp

I saw a function called main!

...

clang-7: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
clang-7: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
clang version 7.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_700/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
clang-7: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to https://bugs.llvm.org/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang-7: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
clang-7: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).

The simple LLVM pass for LLVM-7.0.0

```
#include "llvm/Pass.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h"
#include "llvm/Transforms/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.h"
using namespace llvm;

namespace {
  struct SkeletonPass : public FunctionPass {
    static char ID;
    SkeletonPass() : FunctionPass(ID) {}

    bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
      errs() << "I saw a function called " << F.getName() << "!\n";
      return false;
    }
  };
}

char SkeletonPass::ID = 0;

// Automatically enable the pass.
// http://adriansampson.net/blog/clangpass.html
static void registerSkeletonPass(const PassManagerBuilder &,
                         legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) {
  PM.add(new SkeletonPass());
}
static RegisterStandardPasses
  RegisterMyPass(PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible,
                 registerSkeletonPass);
```

a.cpp program is a simple hello world program.
LLVM_HOME is properly set.
Using prebuilt llvm files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not alone with this error (https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34573), LLVM seems to crash at the end of the program when `RegisterStandardPasses` is used since LLVM 5.

According to this answer: https://github.com/sampsyo/llvm-pass-skeleton/issues/7#issuecomment-401834287 a solution is to add `-Wl,-znodelete` to the compiler flags when you link your program. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Compiling LLVM from source is mandatory if you are developing an in-source pass (within LLVM source tree). It can also be convenient in the case of developing out-of-source passes as it gives you full control over the compilation options. For example, **a debug build of LLVM is much more pleasant to work with** compared to an optimized one. [llvm-pass-tutorial](https://github.com/abenkhadra/llvm-pass-tutorial)

I just came across similar problems. Seems that the optimized clang build (the one acquired from `apt install` or `pre-built binaries`) does not support in-source pass. The only choice I know currently is to build llvm and clang from the source.

[LLVM Download Page](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html).